# Visualforce Page - Replace characters?

Tags: visualforce, administration

I'm not a big Visualforce user (yet?).  I cannot find help for this, so my apologies if this is simple.  I can't find a solution.  :-/

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
Hi There I Need Help {!Lead.firstname}.
</apex:page>
```

In this rudimentary example, how do I code around the sentence and tell it to REPLACE CHARACTERS with something else?   Example, if it were a URL, replace spaces with %20, INCLUDING any spaces in the "firstname" variable being brought in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `URLENCODE` for encoding URLs:

```
{!URLENCODE(lead.firstname)}
```

For other types of replacement, you can use `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
{!SUBSTITUTE(Lead.firstname, " ", "%20")}
```